# Disabling "Your organisation requires Windows Hello" and Windows Hello PIN login

Tags: windows, windows-10, azure-activedirectory, windows-hello

I was setting up a Windows 10 Pro and picked "Setup for an organisation" during the installation when asked. I logged in using my Office 365 credentials (that uses Azure AD behind the doors, I assume). Before the completion of the setup, I ran into "Your organisation requires Windows Hello". Basically I had to setup a PIN and currently get asked of it when trying to login. I can obviously use my password as well, but I am trying to get rid of this PIN/Windows Hello feature all together.

1. How do I disable Windows Hello PIN login throughout the entire organisation? e.g. somewhere in Azure portal, etc.
2. I ran `gpedit.msc` locally, and found out the current status of  `Local Computer Policy / Computer Configuration / Administrative Templates / Windows Components / Windows Hello for Business` is `Not Configured`. Making it into `Disabled` and rebooting didn't solve the problem (even if it did, it'd have to be run on every local machine, I assume). What am I doing wrong with this option?

Comment: Local policy is overridden by all other levels of policy. Otherwise it would be trivial to undo enterprise policy.

Comment: I see, this quite answers 2. But how to change the enterprise level policy then?

Comment: According to [this](https://dannyda.com/2019/11/08/windows-10-sign-in-options-and-windows-hello-set-up-button-greyed-out-after-joined-aad-azure-active-directory/), it can be achieved through Intune settings in Azure portal. However I get 403 when I visit device enrollment.

Comment: You cannot change the group policy unless you are an administrator on the domain.  Since your asking, how to do that, I am guessing that’s not the case.  Which means you have to disassociate your work profile from your machine.  What step of that process are you stuck on exactly?

Comment: I am global administrator. I am looking into disabling this behavior for my organisation, for everyone. MS support tells me that I need further Intune and MDM licenses to be able to edit this behavior.